# SignalR authentication issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-identity

Im working on an ASP.NET core app and I need to implements a chat with SignalR.
Im using Identity with jwt to manage login/permissions and this works fine.

I followed [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0#built-in-jwt-authentication) for implementing authentication in SignalR hub but it doesn't work, my hub functions can be reached even with the [Authorize] attribute on the hub.

This is my code for configuring the service

```cs
services
    .AddAuthorization()
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidIssuer = jwtSettings.Issuer,
            ValidAudience = jwtSettings.Issuer,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jwtSettings.Secret)),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnMessageReceived = context =>
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                // If the request is for our hub...
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && (path.StartsWithSegments("/chat")))
                {
                    // Read the token out of the query string
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

And this is the code I have for my hub

```cs
[Authorize]
public class Chat : Hub<IChatClientMethods>
{
    private readonly ProjectHubContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    public Chat(ProjectHubContext context, UserManager<User> userManager) : base()
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    
    // This method is executed even with the [Authorize] attribute
    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(Context.User); //Always null
    }
}
```

And finnaly the hub mapping

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<Chat>("/chat");
});
```

Why can I call hub functions from client when I provide a random test token ?

Comment: Do you have `app.UseAuthentication();` and `app.UseAuthorization();` before `app.UseEndpoints(...)`?

Comment: Yes I have both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why my [Authorize] tag didn't work.

I used a wrong using.
I used `using MiNET.Plugins.Attributes;`
instead of `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;`